# obtener el ultimo valor de un jtable sin importar cuantas filas tenga java

Tags: java

tengo la duda de como obtener el dato de una celda de la ultima fila de un jtable, he utilizado:

```
jTable1.getValueAt(1,0).toString();
```

pero solo me muestra un dato en especifico, quisiera obtener el ultimo valor sin importar cuantos datos tenga el jtable.

Answer (score 2):

Hay dos formas:

A través del modelo que maneja los datos:

```
TableModel modelo = jtable1.getModel();
int indiceUltimaFila = modelo.getRowCount() - 1;
Object valor = modelo.getValueAt(indiceUltimaFila, 0);
```

A través de la tabla directamente que hace las consultas a su modelo subyacente:

```
int indiceUltimaFila = jtable1.getRowCount() - 1;
Object valor = jtable1.getValueAt(indiceUltimaFila, 0);
```

La diferencia entre uno y otro es lo que ve el usuario en la interfaz (segunda opción)  (por ejemplo si reordenó las columnas). vs como se almacenan internamente (primera opción) los resultados pueden ser un poco distintos a lo que se espera. Lo anterior se puede ver [acá](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/javax/swing/JTable.java.html)